# How long can it take for a COM port to become available on Windows?

Tags: windows, serial-port, usb

After a USB device is plugged in, it takes a while for the device to enumerate on Windows and mount as a COM (virtual serial) port. It seems it can takes 2 seconds or more when the device is plugged in directly, or 10 seconds or more if plugged in via a hub.

I currently retry every 2 seconds if I get back "file not found" when attempting to open the COM port, for a maximum of 8 attempts. This means that I retry for around 16 seconds before presenting an error message. However, I sometimes still see the error message in remote logging, meaning that on some machines devices take longer than 16 seconds before they can be opened via a COM port.

Is there any reasonable upper bound that I can use as a timeout?

Comment: Do you have a UI? Can you put up some kind of progress dialog?

Comment: Yes. Do you mean a popup like "Waiting for device.." with a Cancel button?

Comment: Yes, something like that. If not, there might be some hardware arrival notifications you can use if this is some kind of unattended process.

Comment: In this instance the user plugs in the device, presses an Upload button and expects it to work. Most of the time it does, but if it's the first time the device is plugged in it seems that it can take Windows a minute or more to install the drivers and get the device ready, and this is after the COM port number is available (but returns file not found if you actually try to open it).